# Querying Using Variables in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, querying

I am trying to query using the below condition but it is throwing error

```
last_plus30 = df1.Last + df1.Last*0.2
last_minus30 = df1.Last - df1.Last*0.2
data = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_json('abc.json')['result']['sell'])
print data.query('Rate < @last_plus30')
```

Below is the error:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Comment: What is `print(last_plus30)` ?

Comment: 0   0.00001219
Name: Last, dtype: float64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need convert one item Series to scalar by [`item`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.item.html):

```
last_plus30 = (df1.Last + df1.Last*0.2).item()
```

Error means you compare `Series` (one item) with column `Rate`.